# Convert C typedef struct to Swift

Tags: c, swift, struct

I have this C typedef struct:

```
typedef struct _HEADER {
  BYTE              HeaderTag[16];
  UINT16            __unused_field_1;   
  UINT16            __unused_field_2;   
  UINT32            data;       
  UINT64            size;
  UINT32            UpperHeaderSize;    
  UINT32            LowerHeaderSize;    
  UINT32            KeySize;            
  UINT32            bufferEndOffset;
  UINT32            NcefTag;            
  BYTE              Description[128];   
  UINT32            ContainerVersion;   
  UINT32            HeaderSize;         
  GUID              KeyId;              
  UINT32            FileId;             
} HEADER, *P_HEADER;

typedef struct _INITIALIZATION_VECTOR {
  UINT32            Offset;             
  UINT32            __unused_field_1;
  UINT64            __unused_field_2;
} INITIALIZATION_VECTOR, *PINITIALIZATION_VECTOR;
```

I want to convert this C typedef struct to Swift.

Comment: `BYTE`, `GUID`, and `UINT16` (caps) do not look like standard C types...  Where are these coming from?

Comment: These parameters are Windows based C and I'm able to convert to MacOS in C but I need same structure in swift.

Comment: The only reliable way to define a layout compatible  struct in Swift is to define it in C, and import the definition to Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost identical in Swift apart from the headerTag.
I'll start you off:

```
struct Header
{
    var headerTag = [UInt8](repeating:0, count:16)
    var unused_field_1 : UInt16 = 0
    var unused_field_2 : UInt16 = 0
    var data : UInt32 = 0
    var size : UInt64 = 0
    var UpperHeaderSize : UInt32 = 0
    var LowerHeaderSize : UInt32 = 0
    // You can add the rest based on above
}

let headerA = Header()
```

I have no idea what format a GUID is though, but BYTE is UInt8 in Swift.

Note: structs are passed by value in Swift and not by references as in C.

Comment: `[UInt8](repeating:0, count:16)` is an `Array`, which is a fixed-size structure with (opaque) pointers to the element storage. It is *not* layout compatible to the C array `BYTE  HeaderTag[16]`.

Comment: @MartinR is absolutely correct here, headerTag is always 8 bytes in size regardless of the value of count.  I should have realised this.